# Use of “had said” in the “The Archers”

Tags: grammar, past-tense, present-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect, perfect-aspect

In the BBC radio drama *The Archers*, the following conversation takes place:

> **A:**             David, you are not going to say what you saw. You love your family, right?    
>   **David:**   What?  
>   **A:**             Because if you do, then do exactly as what I **had said**.

Why past perfect in this conversation? Can’t we simply say one of:

- Do exactly what **I said**.
- Do exactly what I **have said**.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, there is a slight difference in meaning.  By using 'had said' it gives me the feeling of a reference to a specific utterance slightly further in the past. Whereas, 'have said' is something that was uttered more recently.

I'm not sure if this is correct as I cannot see the whole context of the conversation, but this is the feeling I get.

Comment: More precisely, it seems to indicate that it was said before a particular moment in the past, possibly a moment when David failed to do exactly as he was told.

Comment: This is the whole conversation basically. It's a phone call to be more presize.

Comment: 1Answer is perfectly right. No doubt in it. Thanking you.
mlrao